# DOM Query For Text Element Containing String

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following text node (the node inside `<g>`) being called:

```
<g id="shape29-19">
    <text x="18" y="600">
        <v:paragraph></v:paragraph>
        <v.tabList></v:tabList>
        "Cash Net"
    </text>
</g>
```

with the following query: `document.querySelector("#shape29-19 > text")`. How can I alter my JavaScript query so that I can return all elements that contains a text node containing the "`'Cash Net'`" string?

Comment: If possible, better to modify the structure so that the text is wrapped in an element. DOM selection by text content isn't the best approach.

Comment: It's how the page is rendered, I have no choice in how the nodes are structured

Comment: You'll just have to select the `text` elements, and filter the set to the ones with that text. Just use `querySelectorAll`, and `.filter()` or a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can filter it out:

```
var elems = Array.prototype.filter.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("#shape29-19 > text"),function(x) {
    return x.textContent.indexOf('"Cash Net"') > -1;
}); // elems contains the elements which you're looking for
```

Comment: Can I replace the ID selector in the query with a tag name instead?

Comment: A few notes... You can narrow it down to the `text` instead of `*`; the node collection returned doesn't have a `.filter()` method; the `.innerText` property is non-standard so use `.textContent` instead; No need for `true : false` when you can just return the result of the `>`

Comment: @squint I realised `.filter`  and hence converted it to an array and thanks for other suggestions. Incorporated :)

Comment: +1 looks good. Just one final hint. Instead of borrowing the `.slice()` to do a `.filter()` operation, just borrow `.filter()` and skip the `.slice()`. So... `Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll(...`. A little shorter and faster that way. :)

Comment: @Xenyal there was an extra `(`. Now it should be fine

Comment: It's returning an empty array

Comment: @Xenyal: Debug it in order to figure out why.